# Using an int as the numerical representation of a string in C#

Tags: c#, string, int

I'm trying to use an integer as the numerical representation of a string, for example, storing "ABCD" as 0x41424344.  However, when it comes to output, I've got to convert the integer back into 4 ASCII characters.  Right now, I'm using bit shifts and masking, as follows:

```
int value = 0x41424344;
string s = new string (
              new char [] { 
                 (char)(value >> 24), 
                 (char)(value >> 16 & 0xFF),
                 (char)(value >> 8 & 0xFF),
                 (char)(value & 0xFF) });
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?  I've tried various casts, but the compiler, as expected, complained about it.

Comment: If you explain _why_ you are doing this, we may have a better solution.

Comment: Do you only need to support ASCII or does this need to take different encodings into account?

Comment: Yep, my first thought was exactly that: "Dear God, why???"

Comment: Maybe to encode a FourCC tag?

Comment: This is being used in an assembler, so the integer value of the string is used fairly often, but it needs to be converted to a string one time to create readable output.

This is only going to be using ASCII.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int value = 0x41424344;
string s = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
               BitConverter.GetBytes(value).Reverse().ToArray());
```

(The above assumes that you're running on a little-endian system. For big-endian you could just drop the `.Reverse().ToArray()` part, although if you are on a little-endian system then it would probably make more sense for you to just store "ABCD" as 0x44434241 in the first place, if possible.)

Answer (score 5):

Characters are 16 bit, so you have to encode them into eight bit values to pack them in an integer. You can use the `Encoding` class to convert between characters and bytes, and the `BitConverter` class to convert between bytes and integer

Here is conversion both ways:

```
string original = "ABCD";

int number = BitConverter.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original), 0);

string decoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(number));
```

Note that the order of the bytes in the integer depends on the endianess of the computer. On a little endian system the numeric value of "ABCD" will be 0x44434241. To get the reverse order, you can reverse the byte array:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original);
Array.Reverse(data);
int number = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);

byte[] data2 = BitConverter.GetBytes(number);
Array.Reverse(data2);
string decoded = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data2);
```

Or if you are using framework 3.5:

```
int number =
  BitConverter.ToInt32(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(original).Reverse().ToArray() , 0);

string decoded =
  Encoding.ASCII.GetString(BitConverter.GetBytes(number).Reverse().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string ConvertToHex(string asciiString)
{
    string hex = "";
    foreach (char c in asciiString)
    {
        int tmp = c;
        hex += String.Format("{0:x2}", (uint)System.Convert.ToUInt32(tmp.ToString()));
    }
    return hex;
}
```

It will convert string to hex as you required.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the opposite. Given a number, it should be converted back to the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string ToHexString(string value)
{
    return value.Aggregate(new StringBuilder("0x"),
        (sb, c) => sb.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", (int)c)).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if the string is never longer than 8 chars and a kind of Hexstring, you could use 
the base variable 16 have a look at the Conversion functions from the Convert class.

```
string s = "ABCD";
uint i = Convert.ToUInt32( s, 16 );
MessageBox.Show( Convert.ToString( i, 16 ) );
```

regards
Oops

Comment: This isn't about hex but about ascii, the string can well be `"Aa4@?"`.

Comment: OK sorry I completely misunderstood the question